# Adhesive to stick gasket to surface to prevent falling out during install

Tags: gasket

In case that a gasket or O ring is on the underside of an engine part on assembly, it comes convenient to stick it with some low duty adhesive to prevent falling out during install. What kind of adhesive should be used? Can I use RTV sealant or silicon?

Answer (score 1):

Some gaskets do need a sealant or adhesive, but often just a thin layer of grease can be sufficient.

Often for water pumps where the gasket was vertical this was enough to hold it in place and did not cause leaks.

Comment: My gasket may fall out unless it is glued in its housing